# What type of attribute does a controller have to have to play games like Bayonetta for PC?

Tags: pc, controllers, hardware

I am not a gamer. I bought a generic PS2 controller, a really bad controller by the way. I played some games with it normally like Tomb Raider III (Steam version).
I tried to use it to play Bayonetta for PC, but the controller is not recognized: when I press the buttons I get no response.

Is there some feature/technology that the controller has to have in order to play games "2010's games"?
How do I know if my controller is compatible with a game before buying a game?

Answer (score 1):

Considering the age of Tomb Raider III (1998), I'm guessing your controller uses [DirectInput instead of XInput](https://www.makeuseof.com/xinput-directinput-meanings/).

In short, there are two main ways a controller can communicate with a PC. Most older games/controllers use DirectInput while newer games/controllers tend to use XInput.

If you want to get your DirectInput controller working with XInput games you can try using [Steam's generic controller support](https://www.maketecheasier.com/use-game-controllers-with-steam-games/) or an application like x360ce.

Comment: Some controllers have a switch to select Direct- or XInput (probably not a "generic, really bad" one though).